# Firing Google Analytics event via IMG URL

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

I'd like to fire a GA event on a 3rd party domain without putting any tracking code there. One option was to track that with Google Tag Manager, but we only need to track 1 simple event and also the 3rd party may not want tracking code installed or an iframe.

I'm assuming I can encode the GA event info into the google-analytics/?etc URL and assign it to an IMG src attribute. Then the 3rd party only needs to put an image on their site. This seems to provide all the necessary info to create the URL: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters

I can pass the visitor's client id (value of their _ga cookie) from my source domain to the 3rd party domain via a URL parameter on a hyperlink and then populate that into the IMG src URL. Seems that is mandatory.

Is there something I'm missing? Will this work? Any longer-term concerns?